# Selenium program to select and enter the data listed in the text box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium Program to book bus tickets via amazon pay in amazon website.
Logged in and navigated to amazon pay and clicked on ‘Bus Tickets’ button under the category ‘Travel tickets, Lifestyle Offers’
But unable to enter the state name in the text box "Enter the source city".

code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;`
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Ticket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys("amazon login id");
        driver.findElement(By.id("continue")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys("amazon password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-xshop']/a[1]")).click();
      
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='Buses']"))).click();
        System.out.println("Page loaded");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bs_lp_route\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div")).click();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/[@id=\"bs_lp_route\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div")).sendKeys("Delhi");
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: There is  **backslash** in your xpath for ID value, removed it and it should work: `//*[@id="bs_lp_route"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div` or you can use this xpath too: `//*[text()='Enter source city']`